# Error 400: Bad Request involving Timestamp within JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3 MVC Controller who has a @ModelAttribute parameter of an object

This object contains numerous properties, mostly strings/numbers. It has one java.sql.Timestamp property.

I call this method via browser, passing the properties as separate query string key/value pairs. When I do not pass a key/value pair for the Timestamp everything works fine, it loads the object with all my properties.

But as soon as I try to send a value for the Timestamp proeprty, I get an immediate Error 400: Bad request.

I know i have to send the data string in a specific format, but I just use a JsonDeserializer so that I can parse the string using the format that I want. But when I set a breakpoint inside my JsonDeserializer, it never gets hit. Spring seems to just ignore it. What did I miss?

Some code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json;charset=utf-8", value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ReturnObject doSomething(@ModelAttribute MyObject obj, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {    
    //blah blah
}
```

MyObject:

```
public class MyObject {
    private Integer someNumber;
    private String someString;
    @JsonDeserialize(using=ShortDateDeserializer.class)
    private Timestamp someTimestamp;
    // getter/setters like usual....
}
```

ShortDateDeserializer:

```
public class ShortDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShortDateDeserializer.class);

    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        try {
            String rawDate = parser.getText();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            return new Timestamp(sdf.parse(rawDate).getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse date: "+parser.getText());
            throw new IOException("Failed to parse date: "+parser.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

When I call my service only setting the number/string like so:

```
localhost/doSomething?someNumber=1&someString=xyz
```

Works fine.

When I also attempt to set a value for the timstamp:

```
localhost/doSomething?someNumber=1&someString=xyz&someTimestamp=09/15/2013
```

I get an immediate Error 400: bad request.

What did I miss in order to get spring to use my custom timestamp parsing code when populating MyObject?

Comment: Log your request at debug level and include it in your question. Log package `org.springframework.web`

Comment: try putting '@RequestBody' instead of '@ModelAttribute'

Comment: @luizcarlosfx: yeah that actually fixes it! In fact it was a mistake for me to even use ModelAttribute here, I should be using RequestBody since it is a POST with good amount of data. Thanks for catching that! Though I still would like to know why ModelAttribute cant use the Deserializer, as that still seems like a desireable feature for some GETs without using RequestBody...

Comment: I don't think you can use Deserializer with @ModelAttribute and GET method, since get methods cannot have body you cannot use json

Comment: @luizcarlosfx Thanks for the explanation. Would you mind puting your original comment as an answer so I can mark that as the solution for this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @RequestBody instead of @ModelAttribute.